# Is it fine from security perspective to display the bam.nr-data.net licenseKey in the source code of a page

Tags: newrelic

I working pentesting of an application.

While reviewing the page source of applications home page, I have found the following code snippet:

`window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"6f521120d1","applicationID":"24754586","transactionName":"JwwITUdWXQ1US04SAgMGDEZcV1UESQ==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":53,"agent":""}`

So if you observe, there is something called as **licenseKey** and its value and **beacon** as **bam.nr-data.net** .

Hence can anyone let me know, what is this licenseKey about and is it a security risk to disclose that in the source code of a web page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well i can’t exactly answer the question as you want me to but if you’re job is to find any possible attack vector than why not include in you’re report? worse that would happen is they ignore it but imagine if you did not report this and this leaked key was the cause of a breach

Comment: @mad.meesh Thank you for the response. Can you let me know what is the significance of this licenseKey like is it using for authorization or authentication kind of thing, any idea?